# sharepoint access

Tags: sharepoint

Is there any method available for sharepoint that can do the following:

Create an internet site suing wss3.0. login using fba. no need to login to edit documents from library that logged in user has access to.

change the password of a user from the site?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an internet site using FBA under WSS 3.0. You will need the appropriate license, which I believe is called the "internet connector" license in the case of WSS. I'm not sure what you mean by "no need to login to edit documents from library that logged in user has access to." You can expose a document library to anonymous users even if authenticated users have specific privileges to it, if that's what you mean. You can write a custom web part that will allow administrators or users themselves to change user passwords from within the site.